# Get dates of upcoming recurring days in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter mobile application in which I allow the user to set a reminder for a recurring set of days, for a given number of weeks.

For example:

- Days to set alarm: M, T, W, **Th** (selected), F, Sa, **Su** (selected)
- For the next **5** weeks

How would I be able to find the `DateTime`s for all Thursdays and Sundays for the next 5 weeks?

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime` class has an `add` method that can be used like so:

```
DateTime nextThursday = thisThursday.add(Duration(days: 7));
```